# iAd is darkening tab bar

Tags: swift, xcode6, iad, tabbar

I have gotten iAds working in my tab bar application, but when it loads the iAd in the app, it darkens the color of the tab bar. I put the iAd code in a function, an I call it in all of the view controllers.
My code:

```
func loadiAds()
{
var adBannerView = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.Banner)


func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!)
{

    println("sort of working1")

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!)
{

    adBannerView.alpha = 0.0
    println("sort of working2")

}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!)
{


    println("sort of working3")

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool
{

    println("sort of working4")
    return true
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!)
{
    adBannerView.alpha = 0.0
    println("error1")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not perfect but ... you can try this:

UITabBar.appearance().translucent = false

Hope it helps !